# Validation on input text fields in html

Tags: html, validation, input

Suppose:

There's 
First Name : (box for input first name)

Requirement: i cannot left this field empty,error message should generate if i left it empty.

Solve this only through HTML

Comment: You can have basic validation using only HTML, i would suggest you to use JavaScript for client side validation.

Comment: Use `required` attribute of input element to validate this, again, not recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
first name <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` has a `required` attribute, as such:

`<input type="text" name="username" required>`

This will raise an error if the user tries to submit the form without first filling out the input. That being said, please google this next time.

[W3Schools Page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)